# Extjs scrolling a panel to a position

Tags: extjs

Hi i have a panel and i want to scroll to a particular postiton in that panel how do i do it

```
var tabs= new Ext.Panel({
    id:id,      
    title:text,
    autoScroll:true,
    iconCls:'windowIcon',
    closable:true,
    closeAction:'hide'
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the scrollTop property of the panel's body to the number of pixels you want to scroll down:

```
// Scroll the body down by 100 pixels.
tabs.body.dom.scrollTop = 100;
```

Comment: already tried that one but dont seem to work...this panel part of a tab panel which i am adding dynamically to a tabpanel..using add method

Comment: You will probably be best served by posting a more thorough code example in your question. Simply being in a TabPanel is not going to affect the ability to set scroll position. If you are adding the panel without immediately making it active then you may need to do something like setting deferredRender to false on the TabPanel, but it is hard to say what the problem is without seeing how you are adding panels and how you are attempting to set scrollTop.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the function scrollTo() here,

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Element-method-scrollTo

e.g.

```
Ext.getCmp('graph_panel').body.scrollTo('left',250);  
Ext.getCmp('graph_panel').body.scrollTo('top',200);
```

But scrollTo() function does not bound check to make sure the scroll is within this element's scrollable range whereas the scroll() function does, hence it is best to use the scroll() function.

e.g.

```
Ext.getCmp('graph_panel').body.scroll('left',300);
Ext.getCmp('graph_panel').body.scroll('bottom',300);
```

Comment: what is the use of 'body' represented here?

Comment: 'body' is the body of panel which you want to be scrolled. I don't really get what you are trying to ask. Can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1):

Consider Parent panel have limited size like 400px x 400px and the Child panel available inside the Parent panel which size of 1000px x 1000px. so scrolling done by Parent panel then the code should like as follows...

```
Ext.getCmp('id_of_Parent_panel').scrollBy(500, 500, true);
```

here scrollBy(x-value=500,y-value=500,animation=true) so child panel scrolled diagonally(practcally first horizontally then vertically) by Parent panel...

The following example used to understand more about this concept...
I am using ExtJs 4.2.1

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {            
            title:'Parent',
            height: 200,
            autoScroll: true,
            width: 700,
            id:'Parent',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Child',
                height: 1000,
                width: 1000,              
                items:[{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Please Scroll me....',
                    listeners: {
                        click: {
                            fn: function () {
                                Ext.getCmp('Parent').scrollBy(500, 500, true);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]

            }]
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `preserveScrollOnReload` config property in view config.

```
viewConfig: {
        preserveScrollOnReload: true
 }
```