# How to scroll an extjs panel towards right

Tags: extjs

I have an extjs panel. This panel has dynamic contents added into it every time I press a button. This dynamic content gets added to the end of the panel, which is not visible until I do a manual horizontal scroll.

I want to scroll to the right most side everytime a new content is added and user see that content immediately (without manually having to scroll right)

Is there any way, I can automatically horizontally scroll the panel towards the end of the panel in the right

Thx

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959975/extjs-scrolling-a-panel-to-a-position?rq=1

Comment: what kind of dynamic content to you add? may be a simple solution could be to call the focus() method off that new content.

Comment: So, I have an initial panel like this

Comment: var ItemMainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
       height: 345,
       width: 800,
       layout: {
          type: 'table'
       },
       autoScroll : true,
          items: [
             {
              xtype : 'container',
              action: 'bodyPanelBlock',
              items: [],
              layout: {
              type: 'hbox',
              align: 'stretch',
              padding: 5
              },
             autoScroll : true
         );

Comment: Then dynamically, I add panels into the bodyPanelBlock container
   
   var item = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',
    height: 300,
    width:390,
    layout : {
  type:'table'
 });